# How to set the initial dimensions of browser action popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am new to Chrome extension development.
I have a browser action with a default popup as an html page.
now the problem is that I am providing a height and width to its body but still the popup is coming to be very small.

Comment: Could you provide your code? I'm guessing there is some error in your stylesheet / include, because setting `width` and/or `height` on the popup's body does work fine for me.

Comment: I got it fixed. It was some silly syntax mistake I made.

Answer (score 11):

Add `width` and `height` to the `body`, using the following CSS:

```
body{
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Link a Style Sheet `style.css` to your popup HTML page and then customize it as you wish.